# jquery Date Range Picker - get preset text on selection

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, datepicker

I am using the Date Range Picker (http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/date_range_picker_using_jquery_ui_16_and_jquery_ui_css_framework/) plugin and need to get the selected preset range text.  What is the best way to get the selected preset range text?

Comment: that's a dead link. goes to forbidden.

Comment: interesting, it's working on my computer.  google "filament group date range picker" it should be the first link

Comment: That is odd O_o  I can't open your link in a new tab, but I can open it by googling it or manually pasting it into the navigation bar

Comment: That is very odd.  I've editing the question to provide the link for copying and pasting into a new tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I scoured that code, but the best I could find was to simply use

```
$(".ui-daterangepicker .ui-state-active a").text();
```

Sorry I couldn't be more helpful, but it seems the authors decided to neglect making getters for the various properties. :\